# How do I turn off auto-update on static files? in django (python)

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I want change css. when i change continer height for oncklick function, after 1 second returns the same size, and when i have error console refresh in 1 second and i can't see. how fix? i turn off livereload plugin.It refreshes everything in 1 second.

when i delete {% now "U" %} to css link rel after css is crashed and not work why? this is problem?

this is my codee--->

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
    <title>home</title>
</head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/style.css?{% now "U" %}" />


<body>


{% block content %}
{% endblock %}

<script src="/static/js/homescript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

home.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/style.css?{% now "U" %}" />

{% block content %}

    <form action = '' method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="continer">
        {% for field in form %}
        {{ field.label_tag }}
        {{ field }}
        {{ field.errors }}
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" name="register" id="btn" onClick = "document.querySelector('#continer').style.height = '200px';">
        </div>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

style.css

```
@import url("//cdn.web-fonts.ge/fonts/bpg-glaho-arial/css/bpg-glaho-arial.min.css");

html,body{
    background-image: url("../img/test.jpg") ;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.continer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height:400px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.inp{
    margin: 3px;
    margin-left: 57px;
    width: 180px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;

}

input,label {
    display:block;
    font-family: "BPG Glaho Arial", sans-serif;
    text-align: center;

}

.btn{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.errorlist{
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 220px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 20px;
    color:white;
    text-align: center;

}
.errorlist li{
    padding-right: 28px;
    font-family: "BPG Glaho Arial", sans-serif;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the link tag in head tag in base.html

Remove this line in home.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/style.css?{% now "U" %}" />
```

And the main thing, in this line in home.html:

```
<input type="submit" name="register" id="btn" onClick = "document.querySelector('#continer').style.height = '200px';">
```

it is not

```
#container
```

it is

```
.container
```

class names can be accessed by (.) and id names can be accessed by (#)

so replace that line with:

```
<input type="submit" name="register" id="btn" onClick = "document.querySelector('.continer').style.height = '200px';">
```